# PHP Prepared Statements without mysqli or PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to use prepared statements using the deprecated [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) extension in PHP?  I have a server that will not be getting mysqli or PDO anytime soon and need to do RLIKE lookups against user supplied text.  mysql_real_escape_string() will be used but I was concerned that it would be insufficient.

Comment: how old is the php version you are using? No mysqli? It was introduced in version 5.0 of php, same thing for PDO (did not come standard but can be installed easily since then).

Comment: It's a bad situation on the server.  There are plans in the next year to get a standard LAMP box in place and migrate their old code to PDO but at present the sysadmin says FreeBSD is several versions out of date and he's not willing to try to upgrade or recompile anything for fear of breakage.

Comment: There's a PDO reimplementation in userland for PHP4.x and earlier 5.0 versions. See http://xpdo.org/ or http://ge.tt/44rtW5a/v/0

Comment: Mario- thanks!  I grabbed a copy and will play with it tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a PHP script, using the deprecated mysql API, that demonstrates using PREPARE and EXECUTE.  I tested this with PHP 5.3.15 and MySQL 5.5.29 and it works for me.  However, I don't recommend it.

```
<?php

$x = 3;
$y = 4;

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'xxxx') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test');

mysql_query("SET @sql = 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse'");
mysql_query("PREPARE stmt FROM @sql");
mysql_query("SET @x = $x"); // SQL injection!
mysql_query("SET @y = $y"); // SQL injection!
$result = mysql_query("EXECUTE stmt USING @x, @y");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  print $row["hypotenuse"] . "\n";
}

mysql_close();
```

As I noted in the comments, this sort of misses the point of prepared queries, because you have to interpolate possibly untrusted content into your SET statements.

You really should fix your PHP installation and enable the mysqli or the PDO_mysql extensions, so you can use real API-level prepare and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

You have there the SQL syntax for prepared statements with manual param binding.